# Obtener consultas que se han ejecutado en la última media hora en Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy preparando una vista en `Amazon Redshift` que obtenga las queries que se han ejecutado en la última media hora, dado que hay un script programado en `crontab` que inserta estos datos en una tabla de estadísticas.

El problema es que no consigo obtener dichas consultas entre un tiempo acotado. Es decir: el script programado se ejecuta cada 30 minutos, por lo que intento sacar las queries que ha habido desde el momento actual (cuando se lanza el script) hasta hace media hora.

Esta es la consulta que tengo en dicha vista:

```sql
SELECT stl_query.userid, 
       stl_query.query,
       stl_query."label", 
       stl_query.xid, 
       stl_query.pid, 
       stl_query."database", 
       stl_query.querytxt, 
       stl_query.starttime, 
       stl_query.endtime,
       stl_query.aborted,
       stl_query.insert_pristine
FROM 
     stl_query, stl_wlm_query
where
     stl_query.starttime BETWEEN (getdate())
     and (dateadd('microsec', -1800000000, getdate()))
```

Esta consulta no me devuelve ningún valor.

La otra versión que tenía es esta:

```sql
SELECT stl_query.userid,
       stl_query.query, 
       stl_query."label",
       stl_query.xid,
       stl_query.pid, 
       stl_query."database",
       stl_query.querytxt,
       stl_query.starttime,
       stl_query.endtime,
       stl_query.aborted,
       stl_query.insert_pristine
   FROM 
       stl_query, stl_wlm_query
  WHERE
       stl_query.query = stl_wlm_query.query 
       AND stl_query.starttime <= dateadd('microsec', -1800000000, getdate())
```

Pero los valores que me arroja son anteriores al período de tiempo que necesito.

EDIT: acabo de volver a lanzar una nueva consulta más simplificada, para ver donde está el problema. He probado a castear la condición a fecha, pero curiosamente, ponga `<` o `>` siempre me devuelve valores anteriores:

```sql
select stl_query.userid,stl_query.starttime from stl_query
where starttime > cast(dateadd(min, -30, getdate()) as date)
order by stl_query.starttime desc
```

Es decir, he lanzado la consulta a las 12:40 y estos son los últimos 5 resultados (hay que tener en cuenta que la hora del servidor es UTC y mi zona horaria UTC+2 (España), de ahí ese desfase de lanzarlo a las 12:40 y que salgan las 10:40:

```sql
2019-05-20 10:40:00
2019-05-20 10:39:56
2019-05-20 10:39:53
2019-05-20 10:39:51
2019-05-20 10:39:51
```

Comment: ¿Podrías intentar dos cosas? 1) En lugar de usar `getdate()`  usa `current_timestamp` 2) En lugar de hacer cast a `date`, hacerlo a `datetime`. Comenta los resultados.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras si utilizo `current_timestamp` no me devuelve nada. Aún así el fallo en la evaluación está en que en el clúster de Redshift la hora es `UTC` y en el equipo donde lanzo la consulta, es `UTC+2`. Por ello, nunca me arroja resultados.

Sin embargo, quitándole dos horas también al `dateadd` si me arroja los resultados, pero no puedo estar cambiando la consulta con cada cambio de horario verano/invierno. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener la fecha en `UTC`?

Comment: Revisa [este enlace](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-postgresql/), a ver si te sirve para lo que piden de  UTC. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias @AntonioVenerosoContreras. Siguiendo la documentación oficial y ese enlace que me has pasado, he conseguido afinar la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, he hallado la solución al problema interpretando los valores que me arrojaba. El fallo en la condición del where (`stl_query.starttime <= dateadd('microsec', -1800000000, getdate())`) que he publicado en la pregunta es que `getdate()` obtiene la hora local del sistema (en mi caso, `UTC+2`).

Como el clúster de Redshift está en `UTC`, la hora indicada como condición nunca estaba presente en los datos. He modificado la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT stl_query.userid, 
stl_query.query, 
stl_query."label", 
stl_query.xid, 
stl_query.pid, 
stl_query."database", 
stl_query.querytxt, 
stl_query.starttime, 
stl_query.endtime, 
stl_query.aborted, 
stl_query.insert_pristine
FROM stl_query, stl_wlm_query
WHERE stl_query.query = stl_wlm_query.query AND 
stl_query.starttime >= 
dateadd('microsec', -1800000000, convert_timezone('Europe/Madrid','UTC',getdate())) AND
(stl_wlm_query.service_class = 9 OR stl_wlm_query.service_class = 14)
ORDER BY stl_query.starttime DESC;
```

De esta forma, lo que hago es:

1. Obtengo la fecha del sistema con `getdate()`
2. Indico que la fecha está en `UTC+2` indicando que su zona horaria es `Europe/Madrid` y que quiero convertirla a UTC con la función `convert_timezone`
3. Por último, le resto con `dateadd` los 30 minutos necesarios en microsegundos (unidad de tiempo del campo `stl_query.starttime` de Redshift.

Ahora ya capturo los datos correctos.